# Lost ZFS bpool on 20.04 production system still running

Tags: grub2, boot-repair, zfs

I mirrored the ZFS rpool and the other drives are still working and the system is up.  But bpool was only on one drive and that drive has died.  I removed one of the other drives from the rpool mirror and reparitioned to make space for a new rpool or UFI boot and put rest back into rpool.

I tried grub-install and it said no UFI directory even after mounting new partition (made FAT32) in /boot/efi

The boot-repair seems to need to be run from USB.

I do not have a backup of bpool.  I have other 20.04 systems though.  Can I copy from one of those?

There are files in /boot directory on rpool older than last reboot time. Seems like system made /boot when there was no bpool mounted there during apt upgrade.   Is it possible I was able to reboot ok after losing bpool?   Does not seem like enough files in /boot now

How can I make a new bpool or substitute without rebooting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One by one I detached drives in the rpool. I repartitioned so I had 4 partitions for efi, swap, bpool, rpool.   Then just attached the rpool partition back to rpool and waited resilvering to complete before doing the next drive.

Then I followed the instructions here for making efi and bpool:
https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html

But skipping parts of instructions for rpool as that was already ok.